# Format the date which is selected through Bootstrap ngbDatepicker in angular 2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker

**HTML code**

```
 <form novalidate [formGroup]="udpateObj">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="HDresolutionDate">Resolution Date:</label>
      <input type="text" id="date"  formControlName="DateP" ngbDatepicker
                                    #d1="ngbDatepicker">   

    </div>
  <form>
```

**code in ts file**

```
let dateVal  = backendDate;// am getting date obj from backend and 
  this.udpateObj= new FormGroup({ 
  DateP: new FormControl(dateVal)
});
```

I need to show the date which is coming from backend or selected from date picker in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: there must be option for the format of date in the datepicker you have used. if there is nothing then you have to change manually forma of date using javascript

Comment: is there a reason you wouldn't use `NgbDateParserFormatter`? Per their docs. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

Answer (score 2):

You can use the date pipe like in this example:

```
<input type="text" value = "{{dateObject | myDateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }}/>
```

or implement a custom pipe if selected date is not a Date Object. Find here example for custom pipe (using momentjs) applying the format passed in call or the default format 'HH:mm'

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
declare var moment: any;

@Pipe({
  name: 'myDateFormat'
})
export class myDateFormat implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
     if (value) {
         var date = value instanceof Date ? value : moment(value);
         if (args && args.length > 0)
             return moment(date).format(args);
         else 
            return moment(date).format('HH:mm');
    }
  }
}
```